# array_push for stdClass with numeric keys

Tags: php, stdclass, array-push

I'm trying to use a function similar to `array_push` but for objects (stdClass) in PHP. See what I expect:

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->a = 'foo';
$obj->{'0'} = 'far';

var_dump($obj);
// > object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["a"]=> string(3) "foo" ["0"]=> string(3) "far" }

var_dump(object_push($obj, 'coin'));
// > object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["a"]=> string(3) "foo" ["0"]=> string(3) "far" ["1"]=> string(4) "coin" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function `object_push`:

```
function object_push($object, $value) {
    $object->{max(array_filter(array_keys((array) $object), 'is_numeric') + [-1]) + 1} = $value;
    return $object;
}
```

Use it then as you would use [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->a = 'foo';
$obj->{'0'} = 'far';

var_dump($obj);
// > object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["a"]=> string(3) "foo" ["0"]=> string(3) "far" }

var_dump(object_push($obj, 'coin'));
// > object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["a"]=> string(3) "foo" ["0"]=> string(3) "far" ["1"]=> string(4) "coin" }
```

Peace